# Why is my website still not working with HTTPS?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I have been following the steps in [Adding SSL to your custom domain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#using_strict-transport-security_headers_in_a_custom_domain) but I am not seeing any changes yet. My website is still running with HTTP only.

I have entered all DNS information under [`Custom domains`](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains) and I have a valid `my-cert-1` under [`SSL Certificates`](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/certificates) but my site is not getting loaded if I go to https://www.my-unsecure-website.com

What could I be missing?

---

I have verified that I own this domain weeks ago, so it cannot be that I just have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: Why the down- and close-vote without comment?

Comment: Not the downvotee, but here are some suggestions: a) this question is generally off-topic for SO, it's more of a serverfault question b) you're saying your site does not get loaded but you do not tell use what kind of error you get c) You don't tell us what you expect and how we're supposed to help.

Comment: From what you're saying it's possible that you don't have the necessary CNAME entry in your domain for www that forwards to ghs.googlehosted.com. If that is not the issue it's possible that your certificate chain is incomplete. It could even be something as simple as: your application doesn't allow https and redirects to http.

Comment: Did you do step 5? At times people generally miss that.

Comment: @VikramTiwari XD yeah that was it - I mean it's stupid and I got already downvoted but if you want to provide an answer for others to see then I am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is really simple. Verify that you own the domain, upload your SSL certificate and assign a certificate to that domain.

Generally people miss the process of assigning certificate. Make sure to follow step 5 ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#using_strict-transport-security_headers_in_a_custom_domain)).